# Laravel Schedule Task - weekdays, every 2 hours , from specific to specify time

Tags: php, laravel, cron, task, scheduler

I have scheduled task which working is fine.
every 2 hours , from 7:59, to 18:01.

```
 $schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\Controller@function')->everyTwoHours()->between('7:59', '18:01');
```

However , I only want it to run from Monday to Friday so I added weekdays()

```
$schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\Controller@function')->weekdays()->everyTwoHours()->between('7:59', '18:01');
```

But unfortunately if will start from 00:00 every weekdays. This is not what I want. I want it to start from 8 am to 6pm every 2 hours.

```
+---------+---------------+-------------+----------------------------+
| Command | Interval      | Description | Next Due                   |
+---------+---------------+-------------+----------------------------+
|         | 0 */2 * * 1-5 |             | 2021-10-04 00:00:00 +08:00 |
|         | 0 */2 * * 1-5 |             | 2021-10-04 00:00:00 +08:00 |
+---------+---------------+-------------+----------------------------+
```

Appreciate your help, Thanks

Comment: can you try `unlessBetween` and specify when you don't want it to occur?

Comment: I tried this 
$schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\Controller@function')->cron(* 0/120 8-16 * * 1-5);
Ended up running every hour instead of 2 hour on every weekends from 8 am to 6pm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller add this if check:

```
if(date('D') == 'Sat' || date('D') == 'Sun') { 
  //does nothing
} else {
  //your task
}
```

Comment: This is "Cheating".. Just joking.. A good cheat.. give u a tick